# How to map multiple fields to the same field?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source class like so:

```
public class Order
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string RXEAmount{ get; set; }
   public string RXOAmount{ get; set; }
}
```

that needs to map to this class:

```
public class Item
{
   public int ID { get; set; },
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping looks like this right now:

```
CreateMap<Order, Item>()
 .ForMember( dest => dest.VALUE, m => m.MapFrom( src => src.RXEAmount) )
 .ForMember( dest => dest.VALUE, m => m.MapFrom( src => src.RXOAmount) )
;
```

How do I do this in a way that allows me to map both these fields without replacing the value in VALUE?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to map two properties to `Value` property and *not* replace the value? Do you want to sum the amounts?

Comment: Basically, after I map these, I will need to create two separate Item records each with one of the mapped VALUEs above.  Yes to the not replace question, no to the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the object into two you either don't use the Automapper (which maps one instance into another single instance), or define two named maps and perform mapping twice.

I would go with the first option.

```
var items = new Item[]
{
   new Item { ID = order.ID, Value = order.RXEAmount },
   new Item { ID = order.ID, Value = order.RXOAmount }
}
```

Comment: I tend to agree with you.  This seems to be outside of what automapper supports.